# Не закрывается меню

Tags: javascript, jquery

Что нужно дописать чтобы скрывалось меню? Нажимаю в любую точку браузера меню закрывается, нажимаю на кнопку меню не закрывается, прошу помощи:

```
$('div#header-profile').on("click", function(){
    $('div.header-profile-menu, div.header-profile').addClass('open');
  });
  $('div#header-ntf').on("click", function(){
    $('div.header-ntf-menu').addClass('open');
  });
  $(document).mouseup(function (e){
    var div = $("div.header-profile-menu, #header-profile, div#header-ntf, .header-ntf-menu");
    if (!div.is(e.target) && div.has(e.target).length === 0){
      div.removeClass('open');
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('div#header-profile').on("click", function(){
    if(!$('div.header-profile-menu, div.header-profile').hasClass('open')){
       $('div.header-profile-menu, div.header-profile').addClass('open');
    };
});
$('div#header-ntf').on("click", function(){
    if(!$('div.header-ntf-menu').hasClass('open')){
       $('div.header-ntf-menu').addClass('open');
    };
});
$(document).click(function() {
    var div = $("div.header-profile-menu, #header-profile, div#header-ntf, .header-ntf-menu");
    if(div.hasClass('open')){
       div.removeClass('open');
    };
});
```

Comment: А как сделать чтобы закрывалось и при нажатие на кнопку а не только на любую часть экрана?

Comment: @Владислав, а это не закрывает?

Comment: Закрывает как и закрывало по клику в любую точку браузера, а при клике на кнопку не закрывает(

Comment: @Владислав, я подправил код, сейчас будет закрываться

Comment: Не открывает даже, ошибок не выдает(

Comment: @Владислав, я был бы благодарен, если бы вы мне пример на jsfiddle, к примеру, показали